# How to solve the out of gas problem in executing a complex solidity function consisting lots of iterations

Tags: solidity, remix, myetherwallet, metamask

How to solve the out of gas problem in executing a complex solidity function consisting  lots of iterations and operation.

[This is my code](https://gist.github.com/printfjoby/662004005a4006e31181de3e104084ee)

Comment: Generally the advice would be to carry out operations `idiomatically` but without seeing your code, its hard to advice. I would recommend that you post your code

Comment: I have edited my post by including my code @Data_Kid

Comment: It is getting out of gas when I gave more than 130 addresses as input for the function 'contribute'. And also the function 'findWinners' gets out of gas even for small number of inputs.

Comment: Performing sorts is extremely taxing on the EVM. I doubt that you will get a quick sort implementation working at all.